# HTML with Angular directives doesn't work when appended

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, csv, ng-grid

I'm using ng-grid with the csv plugin tweaked slightly to support internet explorer. The plugin creates a link, and appends it to the proper place on the grid. Prior to my changes, the link worked fine, but didn't use any directives, only html. Now I use the ng-csv directive, which doesn't respond at all, although the button does show up and the html looks right upon inspection. When  the button is clicked on, a csv should be downloaded - right now with just the test data, numbers 5, 4 inside.

Relevant code from ngGridCsvExportPlugin function:

```
    var fp = grid.$root.find(".ng-grid-buttons");
    var csvDataLinkPrevious = grid.$root.find('.ng-grid-buttons .csv-data-link-span');
    var csvDataLinkPrevious2 = grid.$root.find('.ngHeaderButton2');
    if (csvDataLinkPrevious != null) {csvDataLinkPrevious.remove(); csvDataLinkPrevious2.remove(); }
    var csvDataLinkHtml = "<div class='ngHeaderButton2'></div>";
    csvDataLinkHtml += "<span type='button' ng-csv='[\"5\",\"4\"]' ng-hide='true' filename='data.csv' class='csv-data-link-span'><i class='fa fa-file-excel-o excel-icon'></i></span>";
    fp.append(csvDataLinkHtml);
```

Using the following code, I can inject the compiled HTML and see that it's in the DOM using dev tools, but I can't see the actual button itself on the page:

```
 $(function() {
      angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        var link = $compile(csvDataLinkHtml);
        csvDataLinkHtml = link(scope);
        fp.append(csvDataLinkHtml);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to compile the appended HTML and link it to a scope. Check out the documentation for [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

$compile will take an HTML or a DOM element and produce a template function, which can then be linked to a scope.

You may do something like this:

```
var link = $compile(csvDataLinkHtml);
csvDataLinkHtml = link(scope); // or whatever scope you want to attach to
fp.append(csvDataLinkHtml);
```

Comment: this is within a plugin function that isn't an angular module, so i can't just inject $compile in there. know how to inject into this sort of file?

Comment: Well, in your updated example,  I don't see you defining `fp` anywhere. I assume that needs to be updated. Otherwise, you could emit an event from the plugin code that tells an Angular directive to grab and compile some HTML.

Comment: Nvm, found an ng-hide in there. Got it, thanks Bill.